# Find all values of the positive integer $n$ such that $Q(e^{\frac {2πi}{n}})$ contains $i.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field, cyclotomic-fields

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Find all values of the positive integer $n$ such that $Q(e^{\frac {2πi}{n}})$ contains $i.$

$\mathbf {My \ approach}:$ I could only think that $4$ divides $n$ as $Q(e^{\frac {2πi}{4n}})$ contains $(e^{\frac {2πi}{4n}})^n = i.$
But, are these the only values of $n?$

I couldn't approach how to find other values .

A small hint is warmly appreciated .
Thanks in advance .